# how to access audience data from Google Analytics 4 in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

In Google Analytics 4, I can make audience like this

[image]

due to the Quota Limit error on Looker Studio, now I need to visualize the data through my BigQuery. so the data flow will be like this

> GA4 --> BigQuery --> Looker Studio

I have successfully linked my GA4 data on my BigQuery (daily and streaming), but the problem is I don't know how to access the audience data on my BigQuery schema. I can access the audience data easily if I connect my GA4 directly to Looker Studio (without BigQuery) like this

[image]

how to access audience data from Google Analytics 4 in BigQuery? because I need to make it as a data filter on Looker Studio

Comment: Hi there, Can you please let me know the how the data is stored in bigquery table? Is that all json structure, if so, you probably will have to write a view on top of the table to extract the audience data and then use it in looker. hope this helps

Comment: @BihagKashikar the data is automatically exported from GA4 to BigQuery. the exported data is like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Um1WC.png. but the problem is I don't know where the audience data on my BigQuery schema is. I have tried to find in `user_properties` record but I can't find it

Comment: one option I can think of is export the data to GCS in a csv FILE and then open the file in editor and do a ctrl+f search for the audience data string you want. This can atleast help you narrow down if the data exists in the table? let me know how you go

Comment: @BihagKashikar thanks for the suggestion, it seems the Audience data is not automatically exported from GA4 to BigQuery, I can't find any data on the CSV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Audience data is currently not available in the BigQuery event export for GA4 properties.