# is there any API to get Audience data and its user id from Google Analytics 4?

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I have some audience data on GA4

[image]

I previously linked my GA4 to BigQuery but it seems the audience data is not automatically exported if I use BigQuery links from my GA4 admin. I wrote the issue in another stackoverflow thread in here: [how to access audience data from Google Analytics 4 in BigQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75751418/how-to-access-audience-data-from-google-analytics-4-in-bigquery?noredirect=1#comment133632223_75751418)

now I want to make a separate table in my BigQuery populated with audience data and its user_pseudo_id. so the idea is I want to ingest the data from GA4 server to my BigQuery manually and then I want to do full outer join on my BigQuery so I can eventually link the GA4 event to the audience data

is there a way to get the audience data with the `user_id` / `user_pseudo_id` ? Ideally using API

Answer (score 0):

Audience Lists export the Device ID & User ID for a GA4 Audience. After creating an Audience, you first need to Create an Audience List & then Query the Audience List to retrieve the Device & User IDs. See [Audience List Fundamentals](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/audience-list-basics) for a worked example.

The `user_pseudo_id` in BigQuery is equivalent to the "Device ID" in the Audience List API. The Audience List API returns the Device ID & User Id in JSON, and you'll need to manually transform the data into BigQuery as you mention.